# How to convert many 'chr' to factors with ordered levels?

Tags: r, lapply

I'm trying to analyze a large amount of survey data which has a bunch of different kinds of response options. For some questions the responses were "strongly disagree" to "strongly agree" while for others it might be "negative impact" to "positive impact"
so far I've made objects of the columns which map onto different response options

```
impactvars <- c(21:23,130:134)

motiatingvars <- c(24:31)

importantvars <- c(32:37,45:49,70:84,112:117)

satisfiedvars <- c(38:44, 50:54,118:123)

likertvars <- c(55:69,136:152,169:172)

infovars <- c(85:92,101)

usefulvars <- c(93:100, 102, 153:168)

comfortvars <- c(103:111)
```

I've been able to convert all of these to general factors using lapply via the following

```
mydata[,names] <- lapply(mydata[,names] , factor)
```

My issue is that because these data are ordinal in nature, I need to specify the levels and not just have R randomly assign them. Unfortunately the code doesn't work when I try to specify the levels. This was the code I tried:

```
teamsdata_cleaned[,impactvars] <- lapply(teamsdata_cleaned[,impactvars], factor(teamsdata_cleaned[,impactvars],ordered = TRUE, 
                                  levels = c("Negative impact", 
                                             "Slight negative impact", "No impact",
                                             "Slight positive impact", 
                                             "Positive impact")))
```

Is there a way to coerce many numeric columns to factors with specified levels?

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
teamsdata_cleaned[,impactvars] <- lapply(teamsdata_cleaned[,impactvars], function(x) factor(x,ordered = TRUE, 
                              levels = c("Negative impact", 
                                         "Slight negative impact", "No impact",
                                         "Slight positive impact", 
                                         "Positive impact")))
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
teamsdata_cleaned <- teamsdata_cleaned %>%
     mutate(across(all_vars(impactvars), ~ factor(., 
       ordered = TRUE, levels =  c("Negative impact", 
                                         "Slight negative impact", "No impact",
                                         "Slight positive impact", 
                                         "Positive impact"))))
```